# MongoDB unrecognised option --install

Tags: database, mongodb, command-line, terminal, flags

Hello Everybody , I'm trying to install **MongoDB** to play around with NoSQL DB but I have an error and can't fix it by myself.

- I was install Mongo using Brew
- Downloading from official WebSite
- With SSL
- Without SSL
- Set up Path in   `.bash_profile`

But I'm still have the same error when trying to set up DB.

I'm using **MacOs 10.13**

I can't go further from this point , I was trying to do the same without
    without flag `--install`   but I'm always have the same issue

*I can't start Server*

Can Anybody help me and explain why `--install` doesn't work on my platform and how to resolve this issue.

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.9/data/db --logpath /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.9/log/mongo.log --logappend --rest  --install
```

Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--install'

try 'mongod --help' for more information

---

[image: Terminal Error]

## Update #1

**1.** I was trying to write the same command without `--install` but this solution give me option to start server just once and from another terminal window , after that if I close terminal I can't start server again.

[image: without install]

**2.** Using `Sudo` give me the same error.

**3.**  `mongod --version` give me this

[image: mongo version]

Answer (score 2):

First, try entering `mongod --version` to see if a version is already installed.

Next, try just running the original command without the `--install`.

If none of those work, then try running your original command with `sudo` at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you , i update my question , your advise doesn't help me unfortunately .

Comment: Mongod must be run separately in a terminal window while you are using MongoDB. It sounds like you are getting it to run at least at some point. While your wording is not entirely clear, it sounds like you may be running it and then closing the terminal window without exiting from the process. Then when you open another terminal window and run it again, the port is probably blocked by the previously running process. Look at the list of your running processes and if it is there, kill it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You are clubbing 2 steps togeather.
1. install mongodb
2. launch mongodb

Command given by you is for launching mongodb(dont use --install).
for installing mongodb in mac Os -https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html